# In Rails, is map.resources now obsolete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was viewing an episode in RailsCasts and was looking at the source code for episode 145.

This was his code for the `routes.rb` file

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :orders

  map.current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'

  map.resources :line_items
  map.resources :carts
  map.resources :products
  map.resources :categories
  map.root :products
end
```

I was immediately thrown off. That looked like an entirely different syntax. Then I realized that this source code was published in 2010. I'm wondering if it's now obsolete, because I copied and pasted that code into my Rails Application and it isn't working.

Usually, what I do is

```
resources 'orders'
root 'products'
```

I don't know how I would rewrite `map.current_cart`.

This is the error message I get

```
NameError at/orders/new
undefined local variable or method 'map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::0x4d90868>
```

This line is highlighted

```
  map.current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'
```

Comment: That code is ancient and you shouldn't be trying to learn from it. It's for a now deprecated version of Rails, and it's a dead-end in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is obsolete now.

Instead of map.resources just use resources.

So you should write
resources :orders

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4+ it would look something like this:

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/cart', to: 'carts#show', defaults: { id: 'current' }
end
```

That may be `post` if that's how the route is exercised.

The `map` argument is now gone. `My::Application` depends on the name of the application in question.

As always, have [the routing documentation handy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) when doing things like this.

If you're working on an older application you will have to follow the older conventions.